# Brackets Sprint 40 on Debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, adobe-brackets

Launching Brackets Sprint 40 on Debian Wheezy is throwing following error messages.

```
./brackets: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./brackets)
./brackets: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /<dir>/Brackets.Sprint.40.64-bit/opt/brackets/lib/libcef.so)
./brackets: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /<dir>/Brackets.Sprint.40.64-bit/opt/brackets/lib/libcef.so)
```

Any idea on what is the resolution for this? Will this be fixed in future releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a long thread on that issue here: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4816. To summarize:

- This was caused by a build/packaging issue in the CEF library (the "Chromium Embedded" native component that hosts the UI).
- It will be fixed the next time Brackets integrates a new CEF build. A new build has been available for some time, but it had problems that broke other parts of Brackets, so there's been some delay in integrating it.
- If you're adventurous you can [make a custom Brackets build with the new CEF](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/4816#issuecomment-36767834), though it may be buggy as a result.
- Some people on that thread reported success with swapping in a newer glibc version - but others said doing that causes serious problems on their machine. So best to be cautious.
- Subscribe to that thread on GitHub for updates. (Or subscribe to the [Kanban card for integrating the newer CEF](https://trello.com/c/CySUsuf4/1188-m-integrate-cef-1916-branch-chrome-35)).